# how to extract data from dataframe in python (Index)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to take the feature but not getting the results.

[image]

```
df_close = df['Close']
df_train = df_close[:'2019-12-31']
df_train.shape

training_set = df_close
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)
training_set_scaled[1]

import numpy as np
X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(100, training_set.shape[1]): 
  X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-100:i, 0]) 
  y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0]) 
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
X_train
```

and the result is:

```
array([], dtype=float64)
```

Comment: Is the Date index a string or datetime object?

Comment: it is not showing any data type for the index

Comment: could you share the results from `df_close.index`

Comment: DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-04', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06', '2010-01-07',
               '2010-01-08', '2010-01-11', '2010-01-12', '2010-01-13',
               '2010-01-14', '2010-01-15',
               ...
               '2020-12-17', '2020-12-18', '2020-12-21', '2020-12-22',
               '2020-12-23', '2020-12-24', '2020-12-28', '2020-12-29',
               '2020-12-30', '2020-12-31'],

Comment: Is it correct that you are setting `df_train` but not using it? If so, please leave it out of the question because it's distracting

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `training_set.shape[1]` is smaller then `100` then the inside of the for loop is skipped, leaving `X_train` empty.

You could test this case by adding a print statement inside the for loop. Let me know if it worked, good luck!